# Add random elements to keyed RDD from the same RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

Imagine we have a keyed RDD `RDD[(Int, List[String])]` with thousands of keys and thousands to millions of values:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1, List("a")),
  (2, List("a", "b")),
  (3, List("b", "c", "d")),
  (4, List("f"))))
```

For each key I need to add random values from other keys. Number of elements to add varies and depends on the number of elements in the key. So that the output could look like:

```
val rdd2: RDD[(Int, List[String])] = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1, List("a", "c")),
  (2, List("a", "b", "b", "c")),
  (3, List("b", "c", "d", "a", "a", "f")),
  (4, List("f", "d"))))
```

I came up with the following solution which is obviously not very efficient (note: flatten and aggregation is optional, I'm good with flatten data):

```
// flatten the input RDD
val rddFlat: RDD[(Int, String)] = rdd.flatMap(x => x._2.map(s => (x._1, s)))
// calculate number of elements for each key
val count = rddFlat.countByKey().toSeq
// foreach key take samples from the input RDD, change the original key and union all RDDs
val rddRandom: RDD[(Int, String)] = count.map { x =>
  (x._1, rddFlat.sample(withReplacement = true, x._2.toDouble / count.map(_._2).sum, scala.util.Random.nextLong()))
}.map(x => x._2.map(t => (x._1, t._2))).reduce(_.union(_))

// union the input RDD with the random RDD and aggregate
val rddWithRandomData: RDD[(Int, List[String])] = rddFlat
    .union(rddRandom)
    .aggregateByKey(List[String]())(_ :+ _, _ ++ _)
```

What's the most efficient and elegant way to achieve that?
*I use Spark 1.4.1.*

Comment: Depending on the number of elements, you could first get a set of all possible elements, then broadcast that and use a map function to add them in each entry.

Comment: @LiMuBei The number varies, it could be a thousand or tens of millions. Clarified that.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail how you get from rdd1 to rdd2 in your example? How is the random choice process working there?  You also mention " number of elements in the key" but there's only one element, being a number.

Comment: @maasg rdd2 is just an example, basically it means take this number of any random values from any other keys and put them into the current key that's being processed. " number of elements in the key" is the number of elements in the List.

Comment: @AlexandrNikitin indeed rdd2 it's an example, so my question still stands: how is rdd2 created from rdd1? e.g. `rdd2 (1, List("a", "c"))  = rdd1(1, List("a")) + (random choice from RDD1 = 3) => List("b","c","d") => random pick # elements = 1 => random pick(1) element => List("c") ==> List("a","c")` ??? We first need to put the algorithm down before we can try to solve it with some tech.

Comment: could help if you add your attempt so far.

Comment: @maasg I added my current solution. yes, your algo above is correct. Take any random element from the input RDD. The number of elems to add depends on the number of elemens present.

Comment: did it work? or do you still need help with this?

Comment: @maasg Thank you for your answer! It looks awesome. I plan to try it today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the current approach, and in order to ensure the scalability of the solution, probably the area of focus should be to come up with a sampling mechanism that can be done in a distributed fashion, removing the need for collecting the keys back to the driver.

In a nutshell, we need a distributed method to a weighted sample of all the values.

What I propose is to create a matrix `keys x values` where each cell is the probability of the value being chosen for that key. Then, we can randomly score that matrix and pick those values that fall within the probability.

Let's write a spark-based algo for that:

```
// sample data to guide us. 
//Note that I'm using distinguishable data across keys to see how the sample data distributes over the keys 
val data = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1, List("A", "B")),
  (2, List("x", "y", "z")),
  (3, List("1", "2", "3", "4")),
  (4, List("foo", "bar")),
  (5, List("+")),
  (6, List())))

val flattenedData = data.flatMap{case (k,vlist) => vlist.map(v=> (k,v))}
val values = data.flatMap{case (k,list) => list}
val keysBySize = data.map{case (k, list) => (k,list.size)}
val totalElements = keysBySize.map{case (k,size) => size}.sum
val keysByProb = keysBySize.mapValues{size => size.toDouble/totalElements}
val probMatrix = keysByProb.cartesian(values)
val scoredSamples = probMatrix.map{case ((key, prob),value) => 
    ((key,value),(prob, Random.nextDouble))}
```

`ScoredSamples` looks like this:

```
((1,A),(0.16666666666666666,0.911900315814998))
((1,B),(0.16666666666666666,0.13615047422122906))
((1,x),(0.16666666666666666,0.6292430257377151))
((1,y),(0.16666666666666666,0.23839887096373114))
((1,z),(0.16666666666666666,0.9174808344986465))
```

...

```
val samples = scoredSamples.collect{case (entry, (prob,score)) if (score<prob) => entry}
```

`samples` looks like this:

```
(1,foo)
(1,bar)
(2,1)
(2,3)
(3,y)
...
```

Now, we union our sampled data with the original and have our final result.

```
val result = (flattenedData union samples).groupByKey.mapValues(_.toList)

result.collect()
(1,List(A, B, B))
(2,List(x, y, z, B))
(3,List(1, 2, 3, 4, z, 1))
(4,List(foo, bar, B, 2))
(5,List(+, z))
```

Given that all the algorithm is written as a sequence of transformations on the original data (see DAG below), with minimal shuffling (only the last `groupByKey`, which is done over a minimal result set), it should be scalable. The only limitation would be the list of values per key in the `groupByKey` stage, which is only to comply with the representation used the question.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Awesome answer! I cannot say anything about performance yet. Subjectively it looks and works faster.